# Using Assertion to check array in JSON in API is giving error

Tags: javascript, json, api, postman

I am trying test do an API test using PostMan, I am trying to check if a specific book name exists with the data that is being returned back from the GET call. The data that is coming back is an array.

This is the JSON:

```
{
"docs": [
    {
        "_id": "5cf5805fb53e011a64671582",
        "name": "The Fellowship Of The Ring"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5cf58077b53e011a64671583",
        "name": "The Two Towers"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5cf58080b53e011a64671584",
        "name": "The Return Of The King"
    }
],
"total": 3,
"limit": 1000,
"offset": 0,
"page": 1,
"pages": 1
}
```

This is the test that I have written:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()
console.log(jsonData);
pm.test('Check Book Name, () =>{
_.each(jsonData.docs, (docs)=>{
pm.expect(docs.name).to.eql("The Fellowship Of The Ring");
})
});
```

I am getting following error:

> Your test name | AssertionError: expected 'The Two Towers' to deeply
> equal 'The Fellowship Of The Ring'

I don't understand why its checking The Two Towers instead of The Fellowship which clearly exists within the array

Comment: You're looping through *all* `docs` and expect *each* `name` to equal "The Fellowship Of The Ring"…!?

Comment: Well your code explicitely does : `For each doc in jsonData.docs, expect the title to equal 'The Fellowship Of The Ring'`. So the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting each returned book to have the name `The Fellowship Of The Ring`.

You could use a loop to check for each book:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();

const expectedBooks = ["The Fellowship Of The Ring", "The Two Towers", "The Return Of The King"]

var numberOfBooks = expectedBooks.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++){
    pm.test('Check Book Name ' +  i, function () {
        pm.expect(jsonData.docs[i].name).to.eql(expectedBooks[i]);
    });
}
```